# Partially open type registration in IServiceCollection

Tags: asp.net-core, generics, dependency-injection

I have the following issue registering a generic type definition with IServiceCollection in .NET 7. I'm not really sure if this is supported or if this needs to be defined different to work.

So, let's start describing the problem by starting with the working types classes:

Notification marker interface & wrapper:

```
public interface INotification
    {
    }

public class NotificationWrapper<TMessage> : INotification where TMessage : class
    {
        public TMessage Message { get; set; }
    }
```

NotificationHandler and generic implementation

```
public interface INotificationHandler<TMessage> where TMessage : class, INotification
    {
        void Handle(TMessage message);
    }

 public class GenericHandler<TMessage> : INotificationHandler<NotificationWrapper<TMessage>> where TMessage : class, INotification
    {
        public void Handle(NotificationWrapper<TMessage> data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().ToString() + " :" + data.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Two types of messages

```
 public class MessageM1 : INotification
    {
    }

public class MessageM2 : INotification
    {
    }
```

Now I want to register generic type definition `GenericHandler<>`  for `INotificationHandler<NotificationWrapper<>>`

Option 1:

```
//....
builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(INotificationHandler<NotificationWrapper<>>), typeof(GenericHandler<>)); // compile error -> Partially open type is not allowed on 'typeof' expression
```

Option 2:

```
//...
builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(INotificationHandler<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(NotificationWrapper<>)), typeof(GenericHandler<>));
```

Runtime exception -> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'GenericRegistrations.Services.GenericHandler`1[TMessage]' for service type 'GenericRegistrations.Services.INotificationHandler`1[GenericRegistrations.Services.NotificationWrapper`1[TMessage]]'.'

I want to be able to consume the services as follows:

```
public WeatherForecastController(
        ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, 
        INotificationHandler<NotificationWrapper<MessageM1>> handlerM1)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _handlerM1 = handlerM1;
    }
```

Scanning is not an option as the message can be anything and can be consumed on demand, also this is a shared library between more services.

Is there any solution to this or is it even supported ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any solution to this or is it even supported ?

No, this wouldn't  work this way and its by design, because registering a service with only an implementation type is equivalent to registering that service with the same implementation and service type. This is why multiple implementations of a service cannot be registered using the methods that don't take an explicit service type. These methods can register multiple instances of a service, but they will all have the same implementation type.

Instead, you can do as following:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<INotificationHandler<NotificationWrapper<MessageM1>>, GenericHandler<MessageM1>>();
```

**Note:** According to the design, it wouldn't allow injecting INotification interface as it has same type of implementation which are M1 and M2, so compiler wouldn't perceive which one to register. Therefore, not works or get error.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document for careful reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#service-registration-methods).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! Defining concrete types registration definitely works, as you showed in your demo. I was interested if ServiceCollection supports registering complex open generic types. I want to avoid registering manually since INotificationHandler is actually the handler for MediatR and I wanted a generic consumer to be registered once for any type.

Comment: I got your point, but  since the design doesn's allow us to achive this way and if you have gone through the documentation would wound understand which is logical as well.